# Why does Hartman need to take Sam's bodily fluids in chapter 2?

Tags: death-stranding

In the first chapter of *Death Stranding*, Deadman says to Sam that he took his body fluids (blood?).

> **Deadman**: During that time, we took the liberty of collecting fluid samples from you. You’re a repatriate. That makes you very special.

Then, in chapter 2, Sam asks Deadman to analyze his boots soaked in blood (he says he already took his blood). When Sam takes a shower, Heartman tells Sam that he will take his body fluids for him to test with the BTs.

> **Heartman**: ... When you relieve yourself, a certain amount of chiral matter is flushed from your system. Chiral matter can adversely affect hormone secretion and nervous function. There’s a correlation between exposure and the development of phobias, as well as-in extreme cases-violent and suicidal impulses. Chiralium contamination has even been postulated as a trigger for the onset of DOOMS. Allow me to collect a sample of your excretions for my studies. They provide a non-invasive means to monitor your exposure to chirallum and your overall health.

If Deadman already took his bodily fluids in the prologue, why does Heartman needs his fluids again in chapter 2?

Comment: To see if anything has changed, presumably.

Comment: Heartman just likes collecting Sam’s…— ummm, ahem… “bodily fluids.”

Comment: @SillybutTrue - You can never have too much or too many

Comment: I removed your second question about [strands](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Strand_(item)) as we generally have a rule of one question per question. Feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first chapter, Deadman collects fluid samples because he believes repatriates have special properties to their blood, as stated in Chapter 2 (italics mine):

> **Deadman’s Hologram**: Sam, got a moment? I ran an experiment with your blood. It seems you were onto something. After dispersing an aerosolized sample of your blood in BT territory, we observed reduced activity. While this is hardly definitive, as we have no other repatriates to whom we can turn for additional testing… *It does suggest that the bodily fluids of repatriates are repellant to BTs*. Mama had the idea of developing a weapon to test this theory. The prototype should be ready soon… and when it is, we’d like you to test it.

In chapter 2, Heartman collects Sam's excretions to test for Chiralium concentration to determine Sam's exposure levels, in much the same way that current medical science will test for heavy metals in excretion to determine the level of contamination.